# Error when trying to create azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_path with Terraform/OpenTofu

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-rm, opentofu

I am trying to create a path with specific ACLs in Azure storage using Terraform/OpenTofu.
I have something like this:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_path" "example" {
  path = "example"
  filesystem_name = "example"
  storage_account_id = var.storage_account_id
  resource = "directory"

  ace {
    scope = "access"
    type = "user"
    id = azuread_application.example.object_id
    permissions = "rwx"
  }

  ace {
    scope = "default"
    type = "user"
    id = azuread_application.example.object_id
    permissions = "rwx"
  }
}
```

I'm specifying the `storage_account_id` as a variable as the storage account was created outside of Terraform.

However, when I try to apply this, I get the following error:

```
Error: checking for existence of existing Path "example" in File System "example" in Storage Account (Subscription: "abc123"
Resource Group Name: "example"
Storage Account Name: "example"): datalakestore.Client#GetProperties: Failure sending request: StatusCode=409 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service
eturned an error. Status=<nil> <nil>

  with module.example.azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_path.example,
  on modules/example/main.tf line 45, in resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_path" "example":
  45: resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_path" "example" {
```

My first guess was that I was hitting a limitation of the azurerm provider and the control plane API, as I have public network access disabled. However, enabling public network access on a test account did not change the error.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the storage account type. If it's not *Azure Data Lake Gen2*, then you'll get the above error when trying to modify it with `azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_path`.

When I switched to the correct type of storage account, everything worked.